# Installing the FXRuby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fxruby

I'm trying to install the FXRuby gem. I've installed Ruby and Fox with Homebrew on Mac OS 10.7 and I can't figure out how to make it work. Has anyone?

Heres the error print out I have received:

```
gem install fxruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fxruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-fox-dir
    --without-fox-dir
    --with-fox-include
    --without-fox-include=${fox-dir}/include
    --with-fox-lib
    --without-fox-lib=${fox-dir}/lib
    --with-fxscintilla-dir
    --without-fxscintilla-dir
    --with-fxscintilla-include
    --without-fxscintilla-include=${fxscintilla-dir}/include
    --with-fxscintilla-lib
    --without-fxscintilla-lib=${fxscintilla-dir}/lib
extconf.rb:31:in `find_installed_fox_version': couldn't find FOX header files (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:125:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `Check the mkmf.log file for more details.` The mkmf.log might help.

Comment: http://lylejohnson.name/blog/2008/03/28/one-step-installation-for-fxruby-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I've edited the post to include my print out.

Answer (score 4):

The error was occurring because the FOX toolkit was not installed on Your machine. FXRuby is a Ruby interface to the FOX graphical toolkit, so therefore requires FOX to be installed on the machine first. For Mac OS X execute

```
brew install fox
```

This will install dependencies:

```
libpng, freetype, jpeg, libtiff
```

Then install fxruby gem

```
gem install fxruby
```

I am using yosemite (OS X 10.10) and fxruby gem version 1.6.28 get installed successfully on my system

Comment: I had to do `brew tap homebrew/x11` before I could install fox.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this command fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install libfox-1.6-dev
```